How to generate "poetic text" in Python
My problem is: generate "poetic text" as per the commonly accepted definition
My solution is a generalization of my solution to the palindrome problem.
The problem with my solution is resource limitations.
I begin by defining my iterator:
String  :TypeVar = Iterable[T]
StringR :TypeVar = Iterable[R]
HeadTail:TypeVar = Tuple[String,String]
Windows :TypeVar = Iterable[HeadTail]

@typechecked
def heads_and_tails(P:String, index:int)->HeadTail:
    head:String = P[     :index]
    tail:String = P[index:]
    return (head, tail)

@typechecked
def greedy_matcher(string:String, base_case:Callable[[String],bool], res:R, xform:Callable[[Windows],R])->R: # mine
    #logger.info('greedy_matcher(%s, %s, %s)', string, base_case, xform)
    if base_case(string): return res
    n:int                      = len(string)
    r:Iterable[int]            = range(n-1,-1,-1) # decreasing range
    f:Callable[[int],HeadTail] = partial(heads_and_tails, string)
    S:Windows                  = map(f, r)
    Q:R                        = xform(S)
    return Q

Pronunciation:TypeVar = Iterable[String]
Words        :TypeVar = Iterable[String]
Texts        :TypeVar = Iterable[String]
MCBaseCase   :TypeVar = Callable[[Pronunciation],bool]
MCXform      :TypeVar = Callable[[Pronunciation],Words]
MCRecCase    :TypeVar = Callable[[Pronunciation],Texts]
MCMerge      :TypeVar = Callable[[String,String],String]

@typechecked
def mcscroogian_matcher(P:Pronunciation, base_case:MCBaseCase, mcxform:MCXform, rec_case:MCRecCase, merge:MCMerge)->Texts:
    xform:Callable[[Windows],Texts] = partial(mcscroogian_helper, mcxform, rec_case, merge)
    res  :Texts                     = []
    RES  :Texts                     = greedy_matcher(P, base_case, res, xform)
    assert all(isinstance(r, str) for r in RES)
    return RES

@typechecked
def mcscroogian_helper(mcxform:MCXform, rec_case:MCRecCase, merge:MCMerge, windows:Windows)->Texts:
    H:Pronunciation
    T:Pronunciation
    R:Texts = []
    for H, T in windows:
        tail:Words                    = mcxform(T)
        if not H:
            R.extend(tail)
            continue
        head:Texts                    = rec_case(H)
        HT  :Iterable[Tuple[str,str]] = product(head, tail)
        ht  :Texts                    = starmap(merge, HT)
        R.extend(ht)
    assert all(isinstance(r, str) for r in R), R
    return R

With that in place, the solution to the original problem statement (i.e., "generate poetic text") is an application of that iterator:
Word      :TypeVar = str
Phones    :TypeVar = str
PTRule    :TypeVar = Callable[[Phones],Words]
PTBaseCase:TypeVar = Callable[[Pronunciation],bool]
PTXform   :TypeVar = Callable[[Pronunciation],Words]
PTRecCase :TypeVar = Callable[[Pronunciation],Texts]
PTMerge   :TypeVar = Callable[[str,str],str]
PTFilter  :TypeVar = Callable[[Phones],Callable[[str],bool]]

@typechecked
def poetic_text(phones:Phones, F:PTFilter, rule:PTRule)->Texts:
    logger.info('poetic_text(%s, %s, %s)', phones, F, rule)
    P:Pronunciation = phones.split()
    ptxform:PTXform = partial(poetic_xform, F, rule)
    T:Texts         = poetic_text_helper(ptxform, P)
    T               = filter(parseable, T)
    T               = list(T)
    return T

@typechecked
def poetic_text_helper(ptxform:PTXform, P:Pronunciation)->Texts:
    #logger.info('poetic_text_helper(%s, %s)', ptxform, P)
    base_case:PTBaseCase = lambda p: not bool(p)
    rec_case :PTRecCase  = partial(poetic_text_helper, ptxform)
    merge    :PTMerge    = lambda h, t: ' '.join([h, t])
    return mcscroogian_matcher(P, base_case, ptxform, rec_case, merge)

@typechecked # TODO handle inversion, caesuras
def poetic_xform(F:PTFilter, rule:PTRule, T:Pronunciation)->Words:
    #logger.debug('poetic_xform(%s, %s, %s)', F, rule, T)
    t   :Phones                = ' '.join(T)
    tail:Words                 = rule(t)
    f   :Callable[[Word],bool] = F(t)
    tail                       = filter(f, tail)
    tail = list(tail)
    tail = tail[:min(len(tail),3)] # TODO de-neuter or randomize... maybe check practical limits of the machine
    #tail = tail[:min(len(tail),10)] #
    return tail

The new problem statement (i.e., "don't crash the system") has been marked with a TODO which also offers a potential work-around.
Since I am using an abstract algorithm for my solution, I will also demonstrate how I actually use it to solve the original problem statement:
@typechecked
def rhyming_syllabic_text(phones:Phones, n:int=1)->Texts:
    logger.info('rhyming_syllabic_text(%s, %s)', phones, n)
    rule:PTRule = lambda phones: rhymes2_helper(phones, n=n) # regex stuff at the same level of `pronouncing` lib
    return syllabic_text(phones, rule)

@typechecked
def alliterative_syllabic_text(phones:Phones, n:int=1)->Texts:
    logger.info('alliterative_syllabic_text(%s, %s)', phones, n)
    rule:PTRule = lambda phones: alliterations_helper(phones, n=n) # same but the anchor is on the left
    return syllabic_text(phones, rule)

@typechecked
def syllabic_text(phones:Phones, rule:PTRule)->Texts:
    """ fixed number of syllables """
    logger.info('syllabic_text(%s, %s)', phones, rule)
    return poetic_text(phones, syllabic_filter, rule)

@typechecked
def syllabic_filter(t:Phones)->Callable[[Word],bool]:
    #logger.info('syllabic_filter(%s)', t)
    n   :int                  = syllable_count(t)
    f   :Callable[[Word],bool] = lambda word: n in syllables_for_word(word)
    return f

@typechecked
def syllables_for_word(word:Word)->Set[int]:
    #logger.info('syllables_for_word(%s)', word)
    P:Pronunciations = phones_for_word(word)
    C:Iterable[int]  = map(syllable_count, P)
    C                = set(C)
    return C

By leveraging pronouncing lib, we can generate all but quantitative meter (I'm still working on computing these weights correctly). For reference:
# WIP !!!

Term:TypeVar = str

@typechecked
def weights(t:Phones)->Iterable[int]:
    #logger.info('weights(%s)', t)
    # TODO this is not detecting macrons, etc.
    T:Iterable[Term]           = t.split()
    K:Callable[[Term],bool]    = lambda term: bool(d_re.search(term))
    G:Iterable[Term]           = [tuple(g) for k,g in groupby(T, K) if k]
    W:Iterable[int]            = map(len, G)
    W                          = tuple(W)
    return W

@typechecked
def weights_for_word(word:Word)->Set[Iterable[int]]:
    #logger.info('weights_for_word(%s)', word)
    P:Pronunciations          = phones_for_word(word)
    W:Iterable[Iterable[int]] = map(weights, P)
    W                         = set(W)
    return W

Since rhyming rules are parameterized, they can be replaced with more difficult rules, specifically slant rhymes. I am currently evaluating different solutions to this sub-problem:

https://github.com/Tareq62/multisyllabic-rhymer.git
https://github.com/scottgilmartin/DEFT.git
hand-rolling something with a Dict and some regexes

Current workaround: generate a subset of all poetic text; see TODO.
